# Is Fetching Data in App.js file allowed in React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern

I have built authorization into my React App using passport.js, and I would like to, in my App.js file, fetch my authorization routes to see if a user is logged into the app, or if nobody is logged in.

To help with the question, I have shared a condensed version of my React App's App.js file, and Index.js file.

```
// App.js File

// Import React Libraries, Routes, Container Pages
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { userActions } from './actions/auth/auth-actions.js';
import GameLanding from './containers/StatsPages/Game/GameLanding';
import AppFooter from './components/AppFooter';

// And Create The App
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(userActions.authorize());
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>    
                <Route exact path='/stats/games' render={() => <GameLanding userInfo={this.props.userInfo} />} />
                <AppFooter />
            </div>
        );
    }
}

// export default App;
function mapStateToProps(reduxState) {
    return {
        userInfo: reduxState.authorizedReducer.userInfo,
        authorized: reduxState.authorizedReducer.authorized,
        loading: reduxState.authorizedReducer.loading
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

... my entire App.js file has ~15 Routes components, and (part of) my goal with my App.js file is to fetch the `authorized` and `userInfo` props, and pass these to the components in the various routes. I showed an example where I pass the userInfo prop to the GameLanding component.

Here is how I have set up my Index.js file.

```
// Index.js

// Import Libraries
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

// Import CSS and the App
import App from './App';
import 'react-table/react-table.css';
import './index.css';
import './App.css';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <App />
        </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

**My current problem is as such:** For some reason, fetching the `userInfo` and `authorized` props is breaking my app. I am unfortunately getting no error messages... rather, all of the react-router-dom Links in my app are simply not working... clicking them changes the url, but the pages of my app no longer change...

My questions are then, (a) am i allowed to fetch authorization data in App.js in the manner I am doing so (using connect, with mapStateToProps, etc.), or am I doing this all wrong?

Whether or not somebody is logged into my app is an app-wide thing, not a page-specific thing, and I figured for this reason (also to prevent having to fetch auth props in many many container pages) that App.js is the best place to grab these props.

Any thoughts on why my app is breaking, or how else my App.js file should look (I am ~99% sure my index.js is fine), would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**Edit:** For reference, doing the following: (i) importing userActions, (ii) calling userActions.authorize() in componentDidMount, (iii) including the mapStateToProps and connect on bottom of app, etc. works for loading the auth props in any of my container components. e.g. if i had this code in my GameLanding component, it doesnt break the react-router-dom Links app-wide in the same manner that it does when this code is in App.js. Hence the title of the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) **Reason for app breaking:**

I am assuming userInfo and authorized props will be undefined, as component renders initially before componentDidMount runs and you have not handled undefined props. You could also pass default props for these props.

2) **Better structure for authorization**
I am assuming you need to authenticate each route for authorization.

i) Create routes file and enter all routes for your app.

ii) `<Route exact path='/stats/games' component={GameLanding} onEnter={reqAuth}/>`

Inside reqAuth function you should check if the user is authorized for that route or not.

iii) Inside App component call action for fetching data, store in store and use GameLanding as child component and pass props only when they are defined.

That is not whole code, but should give you gist.

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: The props are initially undefined, but once the routes are fetched, the values for the props are filling in. Are there any guides / resources on best practices with auth throughout a react app?

Comment: Every app has different way of handling auth according to requirement, but you could refer to [link](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/) that could help with the structure of your code.